# Image Transform change causes 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: image-transforms

I had an image transform set on an entry that was working as expected. I updated the code, and it didn't work, so I reverted back to the old transform. It was literally going from

```
src="{{ image.getUrl('featuredImage') }}"
```

to

```
src="{{ image.getUrl('cardImage') }}"
```

The image didn't load, so I reverted back to featuredImage, and it still isn't working. I checked my server logs and there wasn't anything noticeable. In my dev console the request URL is `Request URL:https://example.com/index.php?p=actions/assets/generate-transform&transformId=1` and `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error`

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check Craft's logs at `storage/logs`

Comment: Is devMode on? If it is, you should see more than just the server error code.

Comment: Is your transform setup in the admin area or a template transform? If it's in the template code, is it inside of a cache tag?

Comment: @BradBell Thanks for the reminder. I think I know the root of the problem, but not sure how to solve it:

Some weeks ago, my user (User1) became "corrupted" somehow. My hosting provider's solution was create a new user (User2) and move everything over there. Mostly everything seems to be sorted, but I'm seeing errors in web.log as follows:League\Flysystem\Exception] League\Flysystem\Exception: Impossible to create the root directory "/home/User1/example.com/img/travels". mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/User2/craft/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php. Any idea?

Comment: Huh... yeah some sort of permissions issue. I think I'd push back on the host to investigate since they seem to be the cause of it. :)